# How to filter for "labels does not contain X" in JIRA/JQL?

Tags: jira

How can I write a JQL query which finds all issues whose list of labels does not include a particular value?

I've tried `labels != "thing-i-dont-want"`, but this did not work (it found no issues, strangely) and `labels not in "thing-i-dont-want"`, with the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a post on [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/60233/how-can-i-search-for-issues-that-do-not-have-a-certain-label) which suggests using the following:

```
status in("open","reopened","inprogress") and (labels not in("OnHold") or labels is EMPTY)
```